# How to print this dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe. I want to iterate through the rows and print out the first three columns. But this doesn't work. `KeyError: '0'`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print row['0'], row['1'], row['2']


                     0         1         2         3         4
1       Libor Rates (USD)    Latest    Wk ago      High       Low
2         Libor Overnight   0.68611   0.68667   0.69544   0.36790
3            Libor 1 Week   0.71889   0.71611   0.72428   0.39070
4           Libor 1 Month   0.78056   0.77056   0.78056   0.42830
5           Libor 2 Month   0.85833   0.84000   0.85833   0.51420
6           Libor 3 Month   1.05650   1.03372   1.05650   0.61820
7           Libor 6 Month   1.36378   1.33489   1.36378   0.86790
8            Libor 1 Year   1.74511   1.69400   1.74511   1.13975
```

Comment: Are you sure you need looping? Try this: `print(df.iloc[:, :3])`?

Answer (score 1):

KeyError is because of you are using `row['0']` it should be `row[0]` (int instead)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print row[0], row[1], row[2]
```